# How do I convert markdown equations to pdf using pandoc

Tags: pdf, latex, markdown, pandoc

I have a markdown document with lots of equations (mathjax I think) which renders fine with the application Marked 2. When I try to convert it to pdf with pandoc to create the bibliography, I get an error.

For example, with

```
\\[ \mu_{s,h,d,y} = \left\{
  \begin{array}{1 1}
    \omega_{s,h,d,y} + \delta_{s}(t_{s,h,d-1,y} - \omega_{s,h,d-1,y}) & \quad  \text{for $t_{s,h,d-1,y}$ is real} \\
    \omega_{s,h,d,y} & \quad  \text{for $t_{s,h,d-1,y}$ is not real}
  \end{array} \right.
 \\]
```

It looks like

[image]

However, when I run

```
pandoc -H format.sty -V fontsize=12pt --bibliography northeast_temperature_refs.bib --csl=american-geophysical-union.csl northeast_temperature_ms2.md -o northeast_temperature_ms.pdf --mathjax
```

with or without `--mathjax` I get the following error

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.268 \textbackslash{}{[} \mu

pandoc: Error producing PDF from TeX source
```

If I try to use `$$` instead of `\\[` like:

```
$$
\mu_{s,h,d,y} = \left\{
  \begin{array}
    \omega_{s,h,d,y} + \delta_{s}(t_{s,h,d-1,y} - \omega_{s,h,d-1,y}) & \quad  \text{for $$t_{s,h,d-1,y}$$ is real} \\
    \omega_{s,h,d,y} & \quad  \text{for $$t_{s,h,d-1,y}$$ is not real}
  \end{array} \right.
 $$
```

I get the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Illegal character in array arg.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.278   \begin{array}{1 1}

pandoc: Error producing PDF from TeX source
```

This is my first time ever trying to write equations outside a canned program so any help would be appreciated. I thought I was doing such a good job when I did quick checks with Marked but apparently it doesn't work with pandoc the way I have it.

I am on a Mac with Yosemite and have MacTex installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that pandoc doesn't cover the array command, as your command doesn't work for me in an IPython notebook. However, replacing the array command with a `cases` statement does work for me:

```
\\[ \mu_{s,h,d,y} = \begin{cases}
    \omega_{s,h,d,y} + \delta_{s}(t_{s,h,d-1,y} - \omega_{s,h,d-1,y}) & \quad  \text{for $t_{s,h,d-1,y}$ is real} \\
    \omega_{s,h,d,y} & \quad  \text{for $t_{s,h,d-1,y}$ is not real}
  \end{cases}
 \\]
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work for me using pandoc conversion of a plain md file at the command line, but if I replace `\\[` and `\\]` with `$$`, then everything works as expected.

Comment: It seems like pandoc doesn't recognize the \\[ and uses $$ instead whereas Marked uses \\[ and doesn't recognize $$.

Comment: The array command should work in both MathJax and LaTeX, as long as Pandoc or Marked/MultiMarkdown pass it correctly.

Comment: array should be available, if not it depends on your latex template, not on pandoc.

Answer (score 3):

Marked uses a different markdown processor under the hood (MultiMarkdown) than Pandoc, which has different syntax for equations (`\\[ \\]` instead of `$$`).  If you want to write in a single format for both Marked previewing/HTML and pandoc PDF/anything else output, you can change Marked's processor to Pandoc (directions [here](http://marked2app.com/help/Custom_Processor.html)). This way you can use `$$` syntax for everything.

Comment: Alternatively, you can run pandoc with the MMD equation extension [turned on](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#non-pandoc-extensions): `pandoc -f markdown+tex_math_double_backslash -t pdf`

Comment: Amazing, thanks so much! Now I can feel like paying for Marked was completely worth it (nice application).